# SSMS 2017 Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AppLocal'

Tags: ssms, assemblies, ssms-2017

I recently installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2017.5 in order to connect to some Azure resources. When attempting to connect to any db (including my localhost) I get an error saying:

> 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AppLocal, Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies.

I have looked in the C:\Windows\assembly\GAC directory and do not see the assembly there as I believe it should be.

Is there some way I can either download the assembly or repair ssms?

UPDATE:

After many hours of struggling I found a procedure to solve this issue.

1. Uninstall SSMS completely
2. Delete the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio directory
3. Reinstall SSMS 17.5 and it should work now.

Looks like its a partial removal on upgrading from previously installed versions.

Comment: Same issue I fixed today by upgrading to Microsoft has SSMS 17.9.1

Answer (score 14):

After many hours of struggling I found a procedure to solve this issue.

1) Uninstall SSMS completely (and all versions of it)

2) Delete the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio directory

3) Reinstall SSMS 17.5 and it should work now.

Looks like its a partial removal on upgrading from previously installed versions.

Comment: This helped me out so much! I appreciate your hard work! Would you mind accepting your answer so everyone can see that beautiful check mark? It helps make this answer stand out

Comment: You should accept this as a answer because it is indeed a good solution. (Or any admin who monitor this)

Comment: I also found just running "Repair" from the uninstaller fixed the issue, rather than completely uninstalling.

Comment: Had a similar issue with SSMS 18, but didn't see the 140 folder in step 2, instead I had followed [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/43b3c518-2c5f-4c54-bae3-485be5be3b08/not-able-to-install-ssms-181-set-is-stuck-showing-quotloading-packages-please-waitquot?forum=sqltools):  1) Removed "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18" folder
 2) Deleted registry key "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio"

Answer (score 2):

For me upgrading to latest version 17.9.1 did help. Upgrade details can be found at following Microsoft page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017 
You can download the SQL Server Management Studio 17.9.1 Upgrade Package (upgrades 17.x to 17.9.1) and install it.
Cheers.